# Is it possible to make a hidden section of a web page that is only visible when using an anchor link?

Tags: html, anchor

I would like to add a section to an existing webpage, but only make it visible if the user types the URL with a particular anchor link. Is this possible? Or is it possible to redirect to a new page if the URL has a certain anchor link?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why this has to be done using an anchor link?

Comment: I submitted a manuscript with a URL with an anchor link. The page already exists so I want to add this section so people with the full link can see it but it is invisible to everybody else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't mind using JS, you can listen to the `onhashchange` event to decide whether the specific section should show.

http://jsfiddle.net/C3kHT/

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange",function(){
  if(location.hash=="#trap") /*show section*/
},false);
```

Sorry that I don't have an IE 8 at hand, so I'm not sure if the fiddle code actually work in IE 8.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect if a url has a certain anchor:

```
var anchor = "#tag";
var url = "http://www.google.com";
if(window.location.indexOf(anchor) !== -1){
    window.location = url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this.  Start out with your hidden section set to `display: none;`, then use jQuery to unhide it based on the hash in the url.

CSS:

```
.hiddenDiv {
  display: none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
function showDiv() {
  if (window.location.hash === '#hashNecessaryToShowDiv') {
    $('.hiddenDiv').css('display', 'block');
  }
}
showDiv();
```

Comment: Not working for me (http://pastebin.com/ntCnn7S7) in Chrome. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you tried it in your actual page?  You won't truly be able to replicate the hash with a pastebin or jsfiddle

Comment: Yeah, I saved that code to a local HTML file and loaded it in Chrome. Should work right?